# How to configure the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin to use the same rules used by the maven-checkstyle-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin codebase that builds with Tycho.  It uses a parent POM that defines the checkstyle configuration. The parent POM isn't in my workspace, it's obtained from a Maven repo.

I appear to have the "Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse" installed.

When I run the Maven build, it generates checkstyle warnings that are different from the warnings I get when viewing the source files in Eclipse.

Obviously, this is because the maven-checkstyle-plugin and Eclipse are using different checkstyle configuration files.  I thought the point of the "Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse" was to configure the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin to use the same rules as the project build uses.

I've seen many questions about this in the past, but I don't know what the current situation is.  Is it even possible to do this, or am I going to have to manually check out the rules file used by the build and manually configure the Eclipse Checkstyle config for each project to use that rules file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Go to Window > Preferences > Checkstyle

[image]

Click on 'New'

[image]

And select your checkstyle configuration file here.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  The parent POM defines the checkstyle configuration.  The parent POM is not in my workspace.  The checkstyle configuration file is present on my local box, but only because it's embedded in the Maven artifact jar in my local Maven cache.  The last statement of my post asked if there's any way to do this without manually checking out the rules file and configuring it manually.  Your first statement says this is possible, but from the description of your solution, it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Ah... I see. This is the only way I know of to set it in Eclipse. For what it's worth, you can specify a URL as the path. It doesn't necessarily have to be on the local machine

Comment: Also, I asked a separate question about this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056065/how-to-make-eclipse-checkstyle-not-report-violations-as-errors), but for some reason specifying this external checkstyle config as the default makes all the violations come out as errors, not warnings as I'd prefer.  Any idea how to fix that?